# Cauchy prior in JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I'm building a multi-level Bayesian model using rJAGS and I would like to specify a Cauchy prior for several of my parameters.  Is there a way to do this in JAGS, or do I need to switch to STAN?  My JAGS model is below.  I'd like to replace the `dnorm` distributions with Cauchy, but JAGS cannot find the standard `R` Cauchy distributions, e.g. `dcauchy`, `pcauchy`

```
model_string <- "model{
for (i in 1:n){
    y[i] ~ dbin(mu[i], 1) 
p.bound[i] <- max(0, min(1, mu[i])) #381 gelman
logit(mu[i]) <- a[dc[i]] + b1*x1[i] + b2*x2[i]
}

b1 ~ dnorm(0,.001) 
b2 ~ dnorm(0,.001) 

for (j in 1: n.dc ){
    a[j] ~ dnorm(g0, tau.a)  #not goj, g1j
}

g0 ~ dnorm(0,.001) 
tau.a <- pow(sigma.a , -2)
sigma.a ~ dnorm(0,.001) 
}"
```

Comment: This is a coding site, but not a code writing service. Please edit your function to include code or delete the question and seek a venue where you can get statistical programming tutoring.

Comment: Updated - the question was not about creating the code but about the capacity of JAGS

Comment: As illustrated in the answer, providing the code allows answers that identify the requested facilities but also allow identification of methodological errors about which you are unaware..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Cauchy distribution is a special case of the t distribution, with 1 degree of freedom ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Related_distributions)). While JAGS does not have the Cauchy, it does have the t distribution.

```
dt(mu, tau, k)
```

Just set k equal to 1 and you have a Cauchy prior

```
dt(mu, tau, 1)
```

I would not set your variance to a normal or Cauchy prior though, considering that variance is always positive (and the normal or Cauchy is not).  Try something like the gamma distribution for your precision.

```
tau.a ~ dgamma(0.001,0.001) # vague precision parameter
sigma.a <- 1/sqrt(tau.a)
```

Comment: Gelman discusses use of _half_-cauchy priors on sd parameters here: [Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ba/1340371048)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the share!

Comment: In JAGS, the half-Cauchy prior for standard deviation (not variance) can be coded by truncating the t distribution: `dt(mu, tau, 1)T(0,)`.

Comment: Gelman recommends a non-informative Cauchy prior `dt(0, pow(2.5,-2), 1)` https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.4011.pdf